# Performance difference between SKShapeNode and SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, performance, sprite-kit, rendering

If I wanted to draw a simple red rectangle, should I use an `SKShapeNode` or an `SKSpriteNode`? What is the performance (speed to render) difference?

Are there any **exceptions** (like applying transparency, or maybe creating a `physicsBody`)?

I know what the primary purpose of both are, but I'm not sure which is better on performance for drawing a **simple** red square.

**Code:**
[image]

```
// Shape
let myShape = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
myShape.fillColor = .red
myShape.strokeColor = .clear

// Sprite
let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SKSpriteNode offers higher performance than SKShapeNode class. [See documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshapenode)

If you want to add physicsbody to SKShapeNode, you should be aligned with shapenode points. For more sophisticated performance use SKSpriteNode. SKShapeNodes are useful when it is difficult to use a texture(may be a custom shape) and for building or displaying debugging information.

Furthermore, drawing/displaying a red rectangle is OK with SKShapeNode.